# How to SUM multiple distinct values and get max value in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm a using distinct select in the Oracle SQL, what I want to do is sum up all the data at specific ID. Example in image:

[image: The ouput of query now]

So for example where PlayerIDFK is 1 I want to sum up TwoPointsMade in one column and ThrePointsMade in another, so for that the result would be

```
PlayerIDFK       TwoPointsMade    ThreePointsMade
--------------------------------------------------
1                 5                  2
```

The query Im using now is:

```
SELECT PlayerIDFK, TwoPointMade, ThreePointMade
  FROM PlayerPerformance
  WHERE PlayerIDFK IN (SELECT DISTINCT PlayerIDFK
                         FROM PlayerPerformance);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could use the groupby-clause where you could group by playerIDFK and sum over twopointsmade and threepointsmade

Something like this might work:

```
SELECT PlayerIDFK, sum(TwoPointMade), sum(ThreePointMade) FROM PlayerPerformance GROUP BY PlayerIDFK
```

if you want to get the max you can do a nested query, something like this:

```
SELECT MAX(inside_query.m1, inside_query.m2) FROM (SELECT PlayerIDFK, sum(TwoPointMade) as m1, sum(ThreePointMade)as m2 FROM PlayerPerformance GROUP BY PlayerIDFK) as inside_query
```

there might be a more elegant way to do it but thats what I got :)

Comment: Yay! :) Is it possible to get MAX() of the Sums now please?

Comment: You mean the max of both the sums

Comment: Well max of each so max of twopointmade and max of threepointmade seperately

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this might help:

`SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT PlayerIDFK, sum(TwoPointMade) as TwoPointMade
  FROM PlayerPerformance 
  GROUP BY PlayerIDFK
  ORDER BY sum(TwoPointMade) DESC
) WHERE ROWNUM = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT PlayerIDFK, sum(ThreePointMade) as ThreePointMade
  FROM PlayerPerformance 
  GROUP BY PlayerIDFK
  ORDER BY sum(ThreePointMade) DESC
) WHERE ROWNUM = 1`